# nullReferenceException when i try to play a sound effect?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm making a soundboard with sound effects and I'm getting :

```
"A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'" 
   when building after 'UI Task' (Managed): 
   Loaded 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll'
```

I did have it working but after changes (overwrote previous version) I have been getting this error and I'm stuck. Java is my first language and with C# I'm a beginner. I have spent countless hours looking for a solution.

The nullReferenceException is coming from loadsound(), I think! I have the sound files(.wav) in a folder called resources and build action:resources and copy to output:do not copy(have tried all options here). Also in references a reference was made to Microsoft.Xna.Framework

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Resources;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Craggy_Island
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // The Resources to play
        private SoundEffect drink;//(plus 23 more effects)

        // Flag that indicates if we need to resume Zune playback upon exiting.
        bool resumeMediaPlayerAfterDone = false;

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Timer to simulate the XNA game loop (SoundEffect class is from the XNA Framework)
            GameTimer gameTimer = new GameTimer();
            gameTimer.UpdateInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33);

            // Call FrameworkDispatcher.Update to update the XNA Framework internals.
            gameTimer.Update += delegate { try { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); } catch { } };

            // Start the GameTimer running.
            gameTimer.Start();

            // Prime the pump or we'll get an exception.
            FrameworkDispatcher.Update();

            //LoadSound("Resources/drink.wav", out drink);
            // Create and load SoundEffect objects.
            LoadSound("Resources/drink.wav", out drink);

        }

        private void LoadSound(String SoundFilePath, out SoundEffect Sound)
        {
            // For error checking, assume we'll fail to load the file.
            Sound = null;

            try
            {
                // Holds informations about a file stream.
                StreamResourceInfo SoundFileInfo = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri(SoundFilePath, UriKind.Relative));

                // Create the SoundEffect from the Stream
                Sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(SoundFileInfo.Stream);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                // Display an error message
                MessageBox.Show("Couldn't load sound " + SoundFilePath);
            }
        }



        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button Current = sender as Button;

            try
            {
                if (Current.Equals(button1))
                    drink.Play();//(other buttons here for other sound effects)



            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't play, sound file problem.");
            }

        }
        #region Zune Pause/Resume

        private void ZunePause()
        {
            // Please see the MainPage() constructor above where the GameTimer object is created.
            // This enables the use of the XNA framework MediaPlayer class by pumping the XNA FrameworkDispatcher.

            // Pause the Zune player if it is already playing music.
            if (!MediaPlayer.GameHasControl)
            {
                MediaPlayer.Pause();
                resumeMediaPlayerAfterDone = true;
            }
        }

        private void ZuneResume()
        {
            // If Zune was playing music, resume playback
            if (resumeMediaPlayerAfterDone)
            {
                MediaPlayer.Resume();
            }
        }

        #endregion Zune Pause/Resume

    }
}
```

Comment: Where in `LoadSound` is the error being thrown?

Comment: I think it's in the catch at end of the method , i also get "can't play, sound file problem" but if the sound does not load then later is inevitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrap my original answer unless you're using XNA for game development on Windows/Xbox.  (Original poster is using it for the Zune.)

Regarding the WAV file:

First problem is that you need to set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`.  (You could use `Always`, but that would be unnecessary.)

Second problem is that its type needs to be set to `Content`.

Comment: hi, so the sound file properties should be set to content right?

Comment: hi Zenexer that seems to have got rid or the nullreference exception ty...but its giving a new error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll and this line is highlighted:   [code]      // Create the SoundEffect from the Stream
                Sound =  SoundEffect.FromStream(SoundFileInfo.Stream);

Comment: if i comment out all loadsound("resources/****.wav",out ****); except 1= loadsound("resources/drink.wav",out drink) and comment out the corresponding if's in "private void button_Click" method, it works fine?? uncomment and then  'System.InvalidOperationException' again? i have 25 sound effects each no more than 6 sec long. any ideas?

Comment: I started another thead for the 'System.InvalidOperationException' [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140809/system-invalidoperationexception-using-xnaframework-for-zune-player-in-p7-app[link]

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the hard approach.  Look into `ContentManager` (accessible as `this.Content` from within the `Game` instance).  You can use `Content.Load<T>(string)` to access your audio file, but you'll need to put the audio file in the content project.  Don't change its type: leave it at the default.  Even it's not a resource, leave it be.  It will be compiled into a different format.  Also, omit the file extension from the parameter passed to `Content.Load<>`.

Comment: is this why i am getting the nullreferenceexception? is contentManager  part of the xna.framework? is there a way to fix the existing code as i actually had it working until some changes stopped it from working which i have no idea which change done it?

Comment: ContentManager is part of the XNA Framework, yes.  You should focus on learning to use that, rather than fixing your existing code.  It has a significant number of advantages, including simplicity.

Comment: ok ty again. part of the reason i did this way was for market release and i read somewhere that if the zune play wasnt checked for play then the app would not gain certification, so would i need to keep thezune stuff in the code?

Comment: Yes.  I'm coming at this from the perspective of a game developer, so my advice might be a tad off track, but you should still have access to ContentManager.

Comment: ty for the help, i got the code in the microsoft site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx there is a sample app the have for download which is done this way heres the link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=229130

Comment: anyone help with the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the game before you are loading the sound:

```
gameTimer.Start();

FrameworkDispatcher.Update();

LoadSound("Resources/drink.wav", out drink);
```

Comment: do you mean the gametimer.start(); is in the wrong location or the frameworkDispatcher.update(); ?

Comment: where would i start the game? i moved gametimer() to loadsound method with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem. Finally I got it accidently as follows:

```
StreamResourceInfo streaminfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("project_name;component/folder_name/Sound3.wav", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
SoundEffect effect1 = SoundEffect.FromStream(streaminfo.Stream);
effect1.Play();
```

AND: 
the Property "Build Action" of the .wav file must be setted to "Resource" and the Porperty "Copy to Output Directory" should be setted to "Copy if newer"

By the way, I´m working with Silverlight5.