# 'System.InvalidOperationException' using xnaFramework to play a sound effect in windows phone 7 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, xna

This is kindof strange, in the code i have one sound effect(i have 24 sound effects in total)if i comment out (23 effects) except loadsound("resources/drink.wav",out drink) and comment out the corresponding "if"'s in "private void button_Click" method, it works fine?? uncomment all sound effects and then 'System.InvalidOperationException'? i have 24 sound effects each no more than 6 sec long. any ideas anyone...is there a limit on the amount of sound files that can be used or maybe i have to clear the stream or something?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Resources;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Craggy_Island
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // The Resources to play
        private SoundEffect drink;//(plus 23 more effects)//there are 23 more here

        // Flag that indicates if we need to resume Zune playback upon exiting.
        bool resumeMediaPlayerAfterDone = false;

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Timer to simulate the XNA game loop (SoundEffect class is from the XNA Framework)
            GameTimer gameTimer = new GameTimer();
            gameTimer.UpdateInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33);

            // Call FrameworkDispatcher.Update to update the XNA Framework internals.
            gameTimer.Update += delegate { try { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); } catch { } };

            // Start the GameTimer running.
            gameTimer.Start();

            // Prime the pump or we'll get an exception.
            FrameworkDispatcher.Update();

            // Create and load SoundEffect objects.
            LoadSound("Resources/drink.wav", out drink);//there are 23 more here

        }

        private void LoadSound(String SoundFilePath, out SoundEffect Sound)
        {
            // For error checking, assume we'll fail to load the file.
            Sound = null;

            try
            {
                // Holds informations about a file stream.
                StreamResourceInfo SoundFileInfo = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri(SoundFilePath, UriKind.Relative));

                // Create the SoundEffect from the Stream
                Sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(SoundFileInfo.Stream);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                // Display an error message
                MessageBox.Show("Couldn't load sound " + SoundFilePath);
            }
        }



        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button Current = sender as Button;

            try
            {
                if (Current.Equals(button1))
                    drink.Play();//(other buttons here for other sound effects)



            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't play, sound file problem.");
            }

        }
        #region Zune Pause/Resume

        private void ZunePause()
        {
            // Please see the MainPage() constructor above where the GameTimer object is created.
            // This enables the use of the XNA framework MediaPlayer class by pumping the XNA FrameworkDispatcher.

            // Pause the Zune player if it is already playing music.
            if (!MediaPlayer.GameHasControl)
            {
                MediaPlayer.Pause();
                resumeMediaPlayerAfterDone = true;
            }
        }

        private void ZuneResume()
        {
            // If Zune was playing music, resume playback
            if (resumeMediaPlayerAfterDone)
            {
                MediaPlayer.Resume();
            }
        }

        #endregion Zune Pause/Resume

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your creating a XNA WP7 application you *should* be loading your sounds from the ContentManager:

1. Make sure your sound effect files are set to

   - Build Acction: Compile
   - Content Importer: WAV Audio File - XNA Framework
   - Content Processor Sound Effect - XNA Framework
2. Load your sound from the ContentManager

Code:

```
drink = ContentManager.Load<SoundEffect>("Resources/drink.wav");
```

Comment: hi, i have build action set to content and copy if newer. i got the code in the microsoft site for the app msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx there is a sample app they have for download which is done this way heres the link go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=229130

Comment: But you said XNA. I told you how to do it in XNA...The sample you mentioned me was NOT in XNA

Comment: The way I just mentioned is the way to do it. did you try it?

Comment: It's actually a Zune application, if I recall correctly from his previous question.  Is ContentManager available for that?  I had told him to use ContentManager and the content pipeline last time, and he didn't seem to have much luck with that.

Comment: Hi, I had a look at the msdn stuff for content manager, i am new to c# and wp7 and zune so its not making a lot of sense without sample code to refer to. I tried this line - drink = ContentManager.Load<SoundEffect>("Resources/drink.wav"); and got an error straight away using build action: compile, which i had no idea how to fix.. thing is i'm not sure what to take out of my existing code and what to implement to use content manager.

Comment: do i get rid of the loadsound method altogether? also in previous question here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135861/nullreferenceexception-when-i-try-to-play-a-sound-effect [link]setting soundeffect properties to content got rid of the nullExceptionError and enabled play of one sound effect. ty for helping guys. @MyKuLLSKI

Comment: Yes DELETE IT! The person who told you how to do it before was wrong. I gave a pretty detailed explanation on how to play SoundEffects with XNA. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802429/playing-background-audio-and-video-both-at-same-time/8807626#8807626

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the "Compression Quality" property under the "Content Processor" property in "File Properties" of the sound file. In my case the "Best" compression was a problem.